# How to get specific ID in SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to echo the content of a specific users information. I am currently using

```
$sql = "SELECT treatment_log.tech,treatment_log.comments FROM customers LEFT OUTER JOIN treatment_log ON customers.id=treatment_fk WHERE customers.id = 12";
```

The number 12 will only echo the content of the patient with ID# 12. How would I be able to echo the content of any users information. In other words, I would also like to echo the content of users 13,14,15 etc individually. What would I have to put in the place of "12" to "GET" the id of the current user being viewed.

I can currently do this using PHP by typing:

```
$_GET['customer_id']
```

Comment: how are you running the sql?

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question, but i just posted my code. Hope that can clarify.

Comment: `WHERE customers.id IN (12,13,14)` will return those  3

Comment: im trying to make 12 into a variable instead, im not trying to echo only 12,13,14. I would like to manipulate the SQL based on the user viewing the page.

Comment: see below, i did not understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, keep the `customer_id` in a variable. Remember, `GET` should never be used with any sensitive data. However, as you have requested, maybe you are aware of this. Do it like below:

```
$cid = $_GET['customer_id'];
```

Then write sql query as following using `?` sign in place of `12`:

```
$sql = "SELECT treatment_log.tech,treatment_log.time,treatment_log.date,treatment_log.titration_parameter,treatment_log.pain,treatment_log.bdi,treatment_log.suicidality,treatment_log.comments FROM customers LEFT OUTER JOIN treatment_log ON customers.id=treatment_fk WHERE customers.id = ?";
```

Then do as follows:

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $cid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

> To know about each of the above lines, read the official manual 
>   for [`mysqli_stmt_init()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php), [`mysqli_stmt_prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php), [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), [`mysqli_stmt_execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php), [`mysqli_stmt_get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

And finally, to get the result, use something like below:

```
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($resultCheck > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: ". $row["tech"]. " " . $row["time"]." " . $row["date"]." " . $row["titration_parameter"]." " . $row["bdi"]." " . $row["suicidality"]." " . $row["comments"]. "<br>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172959/discussion-on-answer-by-rakibul-islam-how-to-get-specific-id-in-sql-query).